# Running a script based on hostname within a group variable

Tags: linux, bash

I'm new to shell/bash and I'm trying to perform a function to clear logs on my Oracle files. The environment I'm working in has to have all logs fully open, but the issue we have is the volumes filling up and not allowing services to restart. I'm trying to create a script to run as a cron job to search directories depending on which group they're a part of (each group has slightly different paths and names).

I've got the script going through the "VMORDER" which cycles through the groups listed. I want it to pull the host name. Is there a way for me to say "If VM belongs to a group (i.e. GP1, GP2, etc) then run "GP1s" script"?

Thanks for any help you can provide :).

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPTDIR=[SCRIPT DIR]
GP1="vm01 vm02"
GP2="vm03 vm04 vm05"
GP3="vm06 vm07 vm08"
VMORDER="GP1 GP2 GP3"


##DIRECTORY PATHS
VCIE_DIRECTORY=[DIRECTORY]

##FILE EXCLUSION LISTING
access_log='access.log'
admin_server='AdminServer.log'
admin_service='adminservice.log'
app_ms_1='app_ms*.log'
app_ms_2='app_ms*.out'
app_wm_1='app_ms*.log'
app_wm_2='app_ms*.out'
audit_recorder_log='DefaultAuditRecorder.log'
jms_log='jms*.log'
osb_log='osb_domain.log'
diagnostic_log='diagnostic.log'

HNAME=$( hostname | cut -d'.' -f1 |  tr [:lower:] [:upper:] )

find_log_rotation(){
    for i in $(VMORDER)
        do
            clear_logs ${i}
        done
}



clear_logs(){


    ##GP1
    if [ $HNAME = GP1];
        find -P $VCIE_DIRECTORY/app_ms{1..4}/logs/ -type f -not -name "$app_ms_1" -not -name "$app_ms_2" -not -name "$access_log" -not -name "$audit_recorder_log" -not -name "$jms_log" -mtime 1       
    fi

    ##GP2
    if [ $HNAME = GP2];
        find -P $VCIE_DIRECTORY/app_wm{1..4}/logs/ -type f -not -name "$app_wm_1" -not -name "$app_wm_2" -not -name "$access_log" -not -name "$audit_recorder_log" -not -name "$jms_log" -mtime 1       
    fi

    ##GP3
    if [ $HNAME = GP3];
        find -P $VCIE_DIRECTORY/AdminServer/logs/ -type f -not -name "$admin_server" -not -name "$access_log" -not -name "$access_log" -not -name "$admin_service" -not -name "$osb_domain" -mtime 1        
    fi
```

Comment: The biggest issue I'm having is trying to get it to check the variables set under groups..

I basically want it to find ${HNAME} and check GP1 to see if the hostname equals one of those two variables within GP1. If it is true, then run the script, else continue to next script.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

When the hostname is something like "vm04" und you do not tr it to uppercase, you could use:

```
if [[ "${GP1}" = *${HNAME}* ]]; then
```

The double [] make it a special syntax, right from the =-sign is an expression.
Do not put quotes around it, that would make it a normal string.

Long answer
Do you really have to look for different files on different servers? When you do not have app_ms_1 files under AdminServer, making the selection of the files to skip easier.

```
SKIP="${app_ms_1}|${app_ms_2}"
SKIP="${SKIP}|${access_log}|${audit_recorder_log}|${jms_log}"
SKIP="${SKIP}|${app_wm_1}|${app_wm_2}"
SKIP="${SKIP}|${admin_server}|${osb_domain}"

find ${VCIE_DIRECTORY}/*/logs -type f -mtime 1  | egrep -v "${SKIP}" | while read file; do
   echo Something with ${file}
done
```

First make sure the code above returns the correct files (should SKIP have ${app_ms_3}, are the wildcards handled correctly).

Do you need to use the HNAME?
Than you might want to rewrite your code:

```
if [[ "${GP1}" = *${HNAME}* ]]; then
   SKIP="${app_ms_1}|${app_ms_2}"
   SKIP="${SKIP}|${access_log}|${audit_recorder_log}|${jms_log}"
   STARTDIR=${VCIE_DIRECTORY}/app_ms{1..4}/logs/"
fi
# Something like this also for GP2 and GP3
find ${STARTDIR} -type f -mtime 1  | egrep -v "${SKIP}" | xargs rm
```